# tensorflowでclassとsaver.saveが一緒に使えない。

Tags: python3, tensorflow

初心者です。
「TensorFlowで学ぶディープラーニング入門」
という本で勉強している最中です。
教科書のコードを少しいじって、Tensorflowでクラスを定義してsaver.saveをつかうとなぜかうまくいきません。
結果の保存されたファイルはクラスを定義せずに書いた方に比べるとmodel.ckpt.indexとmodel.ckpt.meta容量が大きいです（下記参照）。
問題となるのは、その後
saver.restore(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
として、データを読み出そうとすると、前者はうまくいかず、後者はうまくいくということです（後者は本に書いてあったコードなのでうまくいくのは当たり前なんですが。。。）。
pythonは3.6を使っています。
理由がわからず、２週間ほどここで躓いています。
宜しくお願いします。

１）クラスを定義したコード（下記参照）で実行
saver.saveで保村されたファイルとサイズ。
        77 May 29 23:27 checkpoint
  38675264 May 29 23:27 model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
       720 May 29 23:27 model.ckpt.index
     55104 May 29 23:27 model.ckpt.meta

2）クラスを定義してないコード（下記参照）で実行
saver.saveで保村されたファイルとサイズ。
        77 May 29 23:35 checkpoint
  38675264 May 29 23:35 model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
       638 May 29 23:35 model.ckpt.index
     43869 May 29 23:35 model.ckpt.meta

一応どちらも、最適化の処理は行い、最後の３つの出力を見ると。
１）では
Step: 1800, Loss: 660.897339, Accuracy: 0.980500
Step: 1900, Loss: 671.345215, Accuracy: 0.978200
Step: 2000, Loss: 653.030029, Accuracy: 0.980000
２）では
Step: 1800, Loss: 657.612671, Accuracy: 0.980100
Step: 1900, Loss: 795.096313, Accuracy: 0.976200
Step: 2000, Loss: 720.260742, Accuracy: 0.978500

１）クラスを定義したコード

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

np.random.seed(20160703)
tf.set_random_seed(20160703)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

class SingleCNN:
    def __init__(self, num_filters, num_units):
        with tf.Graph().as_default():
            self.prepare_model(num_filters, num_units)
            self.prepare_session()

   def prepare_model(self, num_filters, num_units):
    num_units1 = 14 * 14 * num_filters
    num_units2 = num_units

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='input')
        x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    with tf.name_scope('convolution'):
        W_conv = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, num_filters], stddev=0.1),
            name='conv-filter')
        h_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            x_image, W_conv, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME',
            name='filter-output')

    with tf.name_scope('pooling'):
        h_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME',
                                name='max-pool')
        h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, 14 * 14 * num_filters],
                                 name='pool-output')

    with tf.name_scope('fully-connected'):
        w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_units1, num_units2]))
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2]))
        hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool_flat, w2) + b2,
                             name='fc-output')

    with tf.name_scope('softmax'):
        w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2, 10]))
        b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
        p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden2, w0) + b0,
                          name='softmax-output')

    with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
        t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='labels')
        loss = -tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(p), name='loss')
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)

    with tf.name_scope('evaluator'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,
                                          tf.float32), name='accuracy')


   #        tf.scalar_summary("loss", loss)
   #        tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

   #        tf.histogram_summary("convolution_filters", W_conv)
            tf.summary.histogram("convolution_filters", W_conv)

    self.x, self.t, self.p = x, t, p
    self.train_step = train_step
    self.loss = loss
    self.accuracy = accuracy

    def prepare_session(self):
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        #summary = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        #writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/mnist_df_logs", sess.graph)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/mnist_df_logs", sess.graph)

        self.sess = sess
        self.summary = summary
        self.writer = writer
        self.saver = saver

cnn = SingleCNN(16, 1024)
i = 0
for _ in range(2000):
i += 1
batch_xs, batch_ts = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
cnn.sess.run(cnn.train_step, feed_dict={cnn.x:batch_xs, cnn.t:batch_ts})
if (i % 100 == 0) & (i > 100):
    summary, loss_val, acc_val = cnn.sess.run(
        [cnn.summary, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
        feed_dict={cnn.x:mnist.test.images, cnn.t:mnist.test.labels})
    print ('Step: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f'
           % (i, loss_val, acc_val))
    #cnn.writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    #'mdc_session',global_step=i)
    cnn.saver.save(cnn.sess,"/tmp/model.ckpt")


    #!rm -rf /tmp/mnist_df_logs
    #tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist_df_logs
```

2)クラスを定義していないコード

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

np.random.seed(20160703)
tf.set_random_seed(20160703)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

num_filters = 16

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

W_conv = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,1,num_filters],
                                     stddev=0.1))
h_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x_image, W_conv,
                  strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
h_pool =tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv, ksize=[1,2,2,1],
                   strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, 14*14*num_filters])

num_units1 = 14*14*num_filters
num_units2 = 1024

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_units1, num_units2]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2]))
hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool_flat, w2) + b2)

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2, 10]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden2, w0) + b0)

t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(p))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

i = 0
for _ in range(2000):
    i += 1
    batch_xs, batch_ts = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, t: batch_ts})
    if (i % 100 == 0) & (i > 1800):
        loss_val, acc_val = sess.run([loss, accuracy],
             feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images, t:mnist.test.labels})
        print ('Step: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f'
           % (i, loss_val, acc_val))
        saver.save(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
```

読み出してテストするコード

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

num_filters = 16

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

W_conv = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,1,num_filters], stddev=0.1))
h_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x_image, W_conv,
                  strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
h_pool =tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv, ksize=[1,2,2,1],
                   strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, 14*14*num_filters])

num_units1 = 14*14*num_filters
num_units2 = 1024

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_units1, num_units2]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2]))  
hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool_flat, w2) + b2)

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2, 10]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden2, w0) + b0)

t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(p))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

filter_vals, conv_vals, pool_vals = sess.run(
  [W_conv, h_conv, h_pool], feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images[:9]})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,num_filters+1))

for i in range(num_filters):
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, 10*(i+1)+1)
    subplot.set_xticks([])
    subplot.set_yticks([])
    subplot.imshow(filter_vals[:,:,0,i],
               cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')

for i in range(9):
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, i+2)
    subplot.set_xticks([])
    subplot.set_yticks([])
    subplot.set_title('%d' % np.argmax(mnist.test.labels[i]))
    subplot.imshow(mnist.test.images[i].reshape((28,28)),
               vmin=0, vmax=1,
               cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')

    for f in range(num_filters):
        subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, 10*(f+1)+i+2)
        subplot.set_xticks([])
        subplot.set_yticks([])
        subplot.imshow(conv_vals[i,:,:,f],
                   cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')


fig.show()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,num_filters+1))

for i in range(num_filters):
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, 10*(i+1)+1)
    subplot.set_xticks([])
    subplot.set_yticks([])
    subplot.imshow(filter_vals[:,:,0,i],
               cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')

for i in range(9):
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, i+2)
    subplot.set_xticks([])
    subplot.set_yticks([])
    subplot.set_title('%d' % np.argmax(mnist.test.labels[i]))
    subplot.imshow(mnist.test.images[i].reshape((28,28)),
               vmin=0, vmax=1,
               cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')

    for f in range(num_filters):
        subplot = fig.add_subplot(num_filters+1, 10, 10*(f+1)+i+2)
        subplot.set_xticks([])
        subplot.set_yticks([])
        subplot.imshow(pool_vals[i,:,:,f],
                   cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')

fig.show()

input("何か入力してください")
```

Answer (score 1):

「うまくいかない」の内容がわからないです。エラー? それ以外?

例えば

```
from (クラスを定義したファイル) import SingleCNN, mnist

cnn = SingleCNN(16, 1024)

cnn.saver.restore(cnn.sess, "(モデルを保存したディレクトリ)/model.ckpt")

print('Accuracy: %f' % (cnn.sess.run(cnn.accuracy, feed_dict={cnn.x: mnist.test.images, cnn.t: mnist.test.labels})))
```

としたら 最後に保存したモデルの Accuracy が出ることは確認できました。

インデントが妙なところは直しましたが。

```
(simple_cnn.py)
import tensorflow as tf


class SingleCNN:
    def __init__(self, num_filters, num_units):
        with tf.Graph().as_default():
            self.prepare_model(num_filters, num_units)
            self.prepare_session()

    def prepare_model(self, num_filters, num_units):
        num_units1 = 14 * 14 * num_filters
        num_units2 = num_units

        with tf.name_scope('input'):
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='input')
            x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

        with tf.name_scope('convolution'):
            W_conv = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, num_filters], stddev=0.1),
                name='conv-filter')
            h_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                x_image, W_conv, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME',
                name='filter-output')

        with tf.name_scope('pooling'):
            h_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME',
                                    name='max-pool')
            h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, 14 * 14 * num_filters],
                                     name='pool-output')

        with tf.name_scope('fully-connected'):
            w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_units1, num_units2]))
            b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2]))
            hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool_flat, w2) + b2,
                                 name='fc-output')

        with tf.name_scope('softmax'):
            w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units2, 10]))
            b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
            p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden2, w0) + b0,
                              name='softmax-output')

        with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
            t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='labels')
            loss = -tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(p), name='loss')
            train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)

        with tf.name_scope('evaluator'):
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,
                                              tf.float32), name='accuracy')

        # tf.scalar_summary("loss", loss)
        #        tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)
        tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
        tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

        #        tf.histogram_summary("convolution_filters", W_conv)
        tf.summary.histogram("convolution_filters", W_conv)

        self.x, self.t, self.p = x, t, p
        self.train_step = train_step
        self.loss = loss
        self.accuracy = accuracy

    def prepare_session(self):
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        # sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # summary = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        # writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/mnist_df_logs", sess.graph)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./tmp/mnist_df_logs", sess.graph)

        self.sess = sess
        self.summary = summary
        self.writer = writer
        self.saver = saver
```

---

```
(train.py)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

from simple_cnn import SingleCNN

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

    np.random.seed(20160703)
    tf.set_random_seed(20160703)

    cnn = SingleCNN(16, 1024)
    i = 0
    for _ in range(2000):
        i += 1

        batch_xs, batch_ts = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        cnn.sess.run(cnn.train_step, feed_dict={cnn.x: batch_xs, cnn.t: batch_ts})
        if i % 100 == 0:
            summary, loss_val, acc_val = cnn.sess.run(
                [cnn.summary, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
                feed_dict={cnn.x: mnist.test.images, cnn.t: mnist.test.labels})
            print('Step: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f'
                  % (i, loss_val, acc_val))
            # cnn.writer.add_summary(summary, i)
            # 'mdc_session',global_step=i)
            cnn.saver.save(cnn.sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")

    cnn.saver.save(cnn.sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
    print('Accuracy: %f' % (cnn.sess.run(cnn.accuracy, feed_dict={cnn.x: mnist.test.images, cnn.t: mnist.test.labels})))
```

---

```
(load_model.py)
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

from simple_cnn import SingleCNN

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

    cnn = SingleCNN(16, 1024)
    cnn.saver.restore(cnn.sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
    print('Accuracy: %f' % (cnn.sess.run(cnn.accuracy, feed_dict={cnn.x: mnist.test.images, cnn.t: mnist.test.labels})))
```

なんの問題もなく、最後に保存したモデルがロードできていますよ。
最後に保存していないだけなのでは?

---

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

from simple_cnn import SingleCNN

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

cnn = SingleCNN(16, 1024)
cnn.saver.restore(cnn.sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")

for idx in range(10):
    result = cnn.sess.run(tf.argmax(cnn.p,1), feed_dict={cnn.x: np.array([mnist.test.images[idx]])})
    print('estimated {}, correct {}'.format(result, np.argmax(mnist.test.labels[idx])))

estimated [7], correct 7
estimated [2], correct 2
estimated [1], correct 1
estimated [0], correct 0
estimated [4], correct 4
estimated [1], correct 1
estimated [4], correct 4
estimated [9], correct 9
estimated [6], correct 5
estimated [9], correct 9
```

やはり問題なさそうですが。

Comment: ですから「読めない」の内容がわかりません

Comment: 追記しました。

なんの問題もなく、最後に保存したモデルがロードできている、と書いたのは、Accuracyが一致することが確認できるから、という意味です。

Comment: 有り難うございます。ちゃんと動きました。。。そうか、クラスを呼び出してrestoreするんですね。。

Comment: 追記しましたが行き違いでした。

Comment: quiqui様、丁寧に有り難うございました。丁寧にコードまで付けて下さいました。saver.saveで保存されるのがパラメータだけだと思ってましたが、そもそもそれが違っていたようです。